# Angular2 property return undefined in component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm having a problem with my angular2 app, I'm trying to implement authguard with redirectUrl but I always get undefined redirectUrl when login.

What I'm trying to do is if I navigate to secure route, the authguard will redirect me to login page, then set the redirectUrl in auth.service, then when i click login in login.component, it will get the redirectUrl from auth.service, then navigate to that url. But it always return undefined.

I also have a simple log for each step.

```
from auth-guard: /api
from login.component: undefined
```

auth-guard.service.ts

```
// auth-guard.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;

        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    private checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isSignIn()) {
            return true;
        }

        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
        console.log('from auth-guard: ' + this.authService.redirectUrl);

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
// login.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AuthService } from './../shared/auth.service';
import { LoginModel } from './../shared/login.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
    title: string = "Log in";

    model: LoginModel = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    };

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    login(): void {
        this.authService.signIn(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(() => {
                if (this.authService.isSignIn()) {
                    console.log('from login.component: ' + this.authService.redirectUrl);
                    let redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? this.authService.redirectUrl : '/home';
                    this.router.navigate([redirect]);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
// auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AuthHttp, tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AppConfig } from './../../../app.config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    public redirectUrl: string;

    // more code

    public isSignIn(): boolean {
        return tokenNotExpired(null, localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    }

    // more code
}
```

Comment: where it's return undefined?

Comment: @RomanC in the login.component.ts when i call the login method

Comment: I believe the problem here is that you are both calling `router.navigate` _and_ returning `false` from you check login guard. `router.navigate` is asynchronous but your guard immediately returns false and navigation gets scheduled to happen _afterwards_. You could make your guard asynchronous but, assuming this is the issue, the easiest solution is to just `return this.router.navigate(['/login']);`

Comment: @AluanHaddad no, canActivate needs bool as a return type, and the code is from the angular2 documentation, i think the problem is my component is creating new instance of service, that's why the value is undefine. but i don't know why it's doing that.

Comment: Your are not correct. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html you have a race condition regardless if your navigate is correlated with the redirect. However, if you have multiple instances of the service, it would be for 2 possible reasons: 1. you have _provided_ the service at Component level or 2: you have _provided_ the service in more than one NgModule.